# Where can we find "crawl stats" in the new search console?

Tags: google-search-console

None of the sections in the **new Search Console** seems to contain information about "crawl stats", primarily "Time spent downloading a page (in milliseconds)"

Currently the only option is to go to the old version of the search console through the bottom link ( and that is going to be deprecated soon)

[image]

Comment: Not all features have been moved over to the new interface yet, and not all will. The coverage report provides a lot more granular details on how pages are indexed but not that same graph on Googlebot activity. Maybe it will be added soon. You could use your own server logs to get similar data.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath That could be an answer with a bit of expansion.

Answer (score 1):

It is now called the Coverage Reports in the new interface. It doesn't seem to have all the same functionality though - no ability to test robots.txt file, or configure how url parameters are treated (not at this point in time anyhow).

Comment: I do explore Coverage report regularly, but Coverage report does not have "crawl stats" or any similar metric.

Answer (score 1):

Google say re Crawl stats on new search console:
Currently unsupported features -
Here are some **features that aren't yet supported in new Search Console. To use them you will have to use the old Search Console,** for now.
    * **Crawl Stats data** (pages crawled per day, KB downloaded per day, page download times)
    * **Robots.txt tester**
    * Managing URL parameters in Google Search
    * Data highlighter tool
    * Reading and managing your messages
    * Change of address tool
    * Setting preferred domain
    * Associating your Search Console property with an Analytics property
    * Disavow links
    * Removing outdated content from the index

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9073702?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct, for that moment.

Now Google Webmasters is updated, so if you searched for this question, here is the answer:

Go to "Settings" in the main menu. You see a row "Crawl stats" on that page, click on the "Open report" and you will see the statistics like in the old version, even more extended options than before.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry right now it is only available in old version.
Later on Google Webmaster tools will give an update on it.